# React app.js stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am introducing myself to react for UI development, and have been working through a number of tutorials. From my most recent one, react-hackernews, I ran into an odd issue. I successfully was able to render the UI from app.js to show the front page while pulling in new stories. However, when I quit running my server and returned to the project later on, app.js would no longer work; the other modules do work i.e NewsHeader.html, NewsList.html

Repo: https://github.com/tbcooney/react-hackernews

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Err]

Comment: Does the console log point to a specific file and line number in your code?

Comment: @ms_nitrogen it is unclear because all of these lines throwing back errors are from after browserify packages the modules. It worked before, I closed my server and went out for lunch, came back and it was throwing these errors.

Comment: See if the dropdown in red points to any lines of your code that caused the issue.  Something is being passed through `url` that needs to be converted to a string.

Comment: @ms_nitrogen the dropdown is empty, even tho it indicates that there are errors (as pictured above). When I just looked, it threw 17 errors, and I've changed nothing.

Comment: I'm taking a look at the repo.  What exactly is in each of your `build/js` files?  It looks like each one has the full `jquery` and maybe `react` library in them, at least from a quick glance.

Comment: @ms_nitrogen In ./js/app.js you can see,

var _ = require('lodash');
var $ = require('jquery');
var NewsList = require('./NewsList');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

What is odd, is that all of the other modules work, i.e NewsList.html

Comment: I saw the `require()`s, but I'm also curious as to why each of your `build/js` files are 1.5 mbs each.  `require()` allows you to pull in libs and functions without needing to have a copy in your app, but instead in `node_modules`.

Comment: Look into adding sourcemaps to your browserify routine ~ it will make things like this a lot easier to debug